# How to find the significant variables in a multiple regression given the t-statistic and coefficient?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I know that significance can be identified using the p value. but if the degrees of freedom, t statistic and coefficients are given, how to identify significant variables? should the p value be calculated? if so,  how?

Comment: The software you use for analysis should give you the `p-value` by default as part of the analysis output.

Comment: looks like homework questions to me. ;)

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add `self-study` tag and read its [Wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the p-value can be calculated by what were given.

1. Look for a t-distribution table like [this one](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/t-table.pdf).
2. Identify the row that corresponds to your degrees of freedom. Let's say yours is 22.
3. Scan horizontally and find the value closest but not bigger than your t-statistics. For instance, if your t-statistics is 2.41, then opt of the value 2.074 (at row for df=22) rather than 2.508.
4. Move up to the top, check for the two-tailed p-value. It says 0.05. So, your p-value should be somewhere smaller than 0.05 and bigger than 0.02.

The above method relies on checking table. It's convenient when no computer was around. Now that we have access to much more computation power, you can use software or online calculator.

For example, in Excel, you may use `=T.DIST.2T(2.41, 22)` to get the two-tailed p-value. Its actual value is about 0.0248, smaller than 0.05 and bigger than 0.02. I'd also suggest you to get some complete regression output and try it out yourself to make sure you get the correct answer before attempting to solve your question.

Once you got the idea, feel free to post your actual numbers and how you solved it. This is only the how-to's, if you have questions about the conceptual aspect, talk to your instructor or teaching assistant.